# Pl/SQL: Difference between define and declare

Tags: oracle, plsql, declare

```
DEFINE p_annual_sal = 60000
DECLARE
v_sal NUMBER(9,2) := &p_annual_sal;
BEGIN
v_sal := v_sal/12;
END;
/
```

What is the the use of the "Define" word?

Comment: There this `Google` and it gave me [this](http://plsql-challenge.blogspot.sg/2011/04/define-declarewhats-difference.html) and [this too](http://www.interviewmantra.net/2009/04/main-getchar-scanf-break-continue.html#ques2)

Answer (score 7):

`DECLARE` starts section of pl/sql block (`DECLARE... BEGIN... END;` ) where you declare variables to be used inside `BEGIN... END;` part. (executed on Oracle server)

`DEFINE` is a way to substitute values (in SQL*Plus, SQL dev,...) - substitution done by the client side tool (sqlplus) before sending to server.